# Regex: How to delete the spaces after the string

Tags: regex, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am currently crawling a website. One of the output data points is the following:

```
"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            "]
```

I am using the following regex-expression to get the data point mentioned above:

```
re('([^/]+$)')
```

How do I have to modify it to delete the spaces after the number (17:55)?

Comment: what language are you scraping with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.rstrip()` (pyhton) or `string.TrimEnd()` (C#) or function like that provided by language you use. A lot of languages have some built-in function for this.

Answer (score 0):

This below regex finding the empty space at the end of the string.

```
\s+$
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re.sub()` function and replace where there are more than 1 space with nothing. This should do:

```py
import re
a = '"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            "]'
a = re.sub(r'\s{2,}','',a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can use the expression `^\s+|\s+$`

```
import re
string = "08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            "
re.sub(r'^\s+|\s+$', '', string)
# '08 Nov 2018, 17:55'
```

This removes *both* leading and ending white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```js
var regex1 = /(.*?\d+\s+.*\d+)/gmi;
var str1 = `"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            "]`;
var m1;

while ((m = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex1.lastIndex) {
        regex1.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
}



//Get that part: 8 Nov 2018, 17:55

const regex = /(.*?(\d+\s+.*\d+))/gmi;
const str =
`"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55                       "]`;
let m2;

while ((m2 = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m2.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;    document.write(m[1]);
    }
       console.log(m2[2]); //8 Nov 2018, 17:55
}
```

//Python

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.*?(\d+\s+.*\d+))"

test_str = "\"Kickoff Date\": [\"08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            \"]"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all spaces before tthe double quote:

```
str = '"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55                            "]'
res = re.sub(r'\s+"', '"', str)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
"Kickoff Date": ["08 Nov 2018, 17:55"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop at last non-space character instead of going till end, like this

```
re('([^/]+\S)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a word boundary (\b)

```
[^/]+\b
```

This will match up to the last word character